# System.IO.Directory.GetFiles VS My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to get the names of all the files in a specific directory which includes over 25,000 files. I tried using these methods:

`System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` and  `My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles`

I've found out that `System.IO` is significantly faster `My.Computer`

By significantly I mean around 20 second faster.

Could anyone explain to me the difference between These two methods?

Comment: How did you benchmark it? Did one of them run straight after the other? This would give false results as the system may have cached the directory for faster reading after the first one was called.

Comment: I just used "My.Computer" for a while and then discovered the"System.IO".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i remember this correctly System.IO.Directory.GetFiles uses a indexed file method that is stored in reg, and My.Computer builds the indexed files as it iterates throw the file dir so the second time you used the same My.Computer method if i remember right it will be faster

Comment: your answer makes sense. if this is the case, it explains everything     Thanks.